# JSP trimSpaces directive uri not working

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, jsp-tags

I have the below code with spaces on uri and prefix.Could you please help on how to fix this at the server level?
I cant fix on each JSP page since the no of JSP pages is so high.

I tried JSP trimSpaces but it doesnt work.

```
<%@ taglib uri=" news.tld"  prefix=" news" %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fix this at the server level. The options for trimming whitespace are for template text rather than attribute values.

I'd suggest using Eclipse to do a regular expression based global search and replace to fix this (or any other tool that lets you do a search and replace across multiple files in a single operation). I've used this technique in the past to fix EOL issues in thousands of pages of Javadoc in a single operation.

Comment: Hi. How about trying it with <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces> in the web.xml or having <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> in the JSP page? Will this help at the directive level for the attribute vales?

Comment: Which part of "There is no way to fix this at the server level. The options for trimming whitespace are for template text rather than attribute values." was not clear?

Comment: Hi Mark, Could you please help me with eclipse regular expression for global search and replace to fix? <%@ taglib uri=" news.tld"  prefix=" news" %> replace with <%@ taglib uri=" news.tld"  prefix="news" %>